# Error message in nodejs: backend returned code 400, body was null

Tags: node.js, web, error-handling, angular6, mean-stack

I am developing a web application using MEAN Stack with Angular 6. I am struggling with the following error for days.
I have an input field which shows a color picker. It allows us to select the color.
This is my color schema.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var rdaColorSchema = new mongoose.Schema({  
  colorMovementBox: {
      type : String,
  },
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('rdaColor', rdaColorSchema);
```

This is my back end.

```
router.post('/save', (req, res)=>{
    var rdaColorVal = new rdaColor(
        {
            colorMovementBox: req.body.colorMovementBox,
        }
    );

rdaColorVal.save((err,doc)=> {
    if(!err){

        res.send(doc);}
        else{
            console.log(err);
        }
        });
});
```

This is my service file.

```
export class RdaColorService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

     private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
        if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
            // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
            console.error('An error occurred:', error.error.message);
        } else {
            // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
            // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
            console.error(
                `Backend returned code ${error.status}, ` +
                `body was: ${error.error}`);
        }
        // return an observable with a user-facing error message
        return throwError('Something bad happened; please try again later.');
    };
        private extractData(res: Response) {
        let body = res;
        return body || [];
    }
    saveRdaColor(rdaColor): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.post('/rdaColor/save', rdaColor, httpOptions)
            .pipe(
                catchError(this.handleError)
            );
    }

}
```

When I debug the project I can see color values in the front end(I have used an ngx-color picker to select colors). But the back- end gives following errors.
[image: error]

I searched a lot about this error. But nothing worked.

Comment: Can you share more of your code on the server side? Are you using bodyParser as a middleware?

Comment: You need to send a request body `{ colorMovementBox: "<value here>" }` and incorporate the body-parser middle ware.

Comment: @MattKuhns Yes I am using a body parser. I have added the service file to the question as well.

Comment: @AdiSivasankaran Thanks for your suggestion. Should we send the request body in the service?

Answer (score 1):

Request body was `null`.

You need to:

Send a request body of `{ colorMovementBox: "<value here>" }` from the Angular 6 POST call:

```
this.httpClient.post("/rdaColor/save", { "colorMovementBox": "<value here>" })
    .subscribe(
          data => {
              console.log("POST Request is successful ", data);
          },
          error => {
              console.log("Error:", error);
          }
    );
```

Incorporate the `body-parser` middleware in your express backend via `npm i -S body-parser`:

```
const app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
.
.
.
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```